# The social aspect of having only one dog

Tags: dogs, socializing

I'm thinking of getting a dog, but I read that dogs are social and pack animals so I was wondering if there would be any short and long-term problems with the dog not having fellows around the house.

Are there any short or long-term problems to look out for in the case of having only one dog?

Additional details : I will live alone and I'll be working 8-5pm.

Comment: The dog will adopt you and your family as its pack.

Comment: Hi @keshlam, I added new details I forgot to include. Will there be a difference? : Additional details : I will live alone and I'll be working 8-5pm.

Answer (score 3):

It's best to start with one dog. You need to develop a strong relationship with one dog first.

I'm more concerned that you work from 8-5 and are presumably out from 7-6 every day. You will need someone to visit the dog at least twice every day, to play with him and take him out to relieve himself. Then you will have to spend a lot of your free time with the dog, not going out for the evening (unless you can take the dog too).

This is far from an ideal situation. Can you wait to get a dog till you have more free time to spend with it?

Comment: All of which is part of why some of us settled on cats rather than dogs. Realistically, a dog _is_ a bigger time commitment.

Comment: The time commitment depends greatly on the dog (breed, age, temperament). If everyone who worked 9 hours a day couldn't have dogs, there would be more dog shelters than dog owners! Certainly one should do as much as they can to spend plenty of time with their dog and avoid leaving them along for long periods of time, especially right after adopting them, but it's unrealistic to say "You work for a living, you can't have a dog."

Comment: @Beverly I have seen some people give up their dog because they work a 9-5. If everyone did this, very few dogs would have homes. : ( Many dogs can wait 8-10 hours to relieve themselves, but there's always other alternatives like potty pads or friendly neighbors as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

That's what everyone says, yes, but honestly you and your dog might be happier just as you are. It's really important to sit down and consider all the possibilities:

- if the new dog has a weaker bladder than your current one, you may need someone to let them out
- the more dogs you have, the harder/more expensive it is to travel
- there is always the possibility that the two dogs will not get along or their contentions require more owner skill than you currently possess, such as jealousy issues, food guarding, etc
- there is a very big possibility that both dogs tolerate one another just fine - and that's the end of the story, so they never really play with one another or engage socially
- are you okay with walking two dogs? what if this dog has a significantly higher energy requirement than your current dog?

Many of these questions can be answered by careful choosing what kind of dog would work best and watching - not idealizing, really watching - how your dog interacts at a dog park.

There is no same answer for everyone. But "because your dog might be lonely!" is *never* the best answer.